# A Non-blocking Multicast UDP port in Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, sockets, udp, multicast

I need to add a UDP-Multicast port receiver (listener) to a Matlab program that, in addition to the UDP-port, collects and processes data from two other (TCPIP) ports in real time. Matlab has a built-in UDP function for Unicast UDP, with  callback functions (BytesAvailableFcn and DatagramReceivedFcn), which allow fast and asynchronous data reading. Unfortunately, there is no such function for Multicast UDP in Matlab.

A work-around Java-solution has been previously posted on this forum:

```
socket = java.net.MulticastSocket(DEST_PORT);
socket.joinGroup (java.net.InetAddress.getByName(MCAST_ADDR));
socket.setReuseAddress (1);

packet = java.net.DatagramPacket(
        zeros(1, intmax('uint16'), 'int8'), intmax('uint16'));

while (true) {

    socket.receive(packet);  
}
```

This solution works, but unfortunately it blocks other functions. Another simple but inefficient solution is to use a timer function. However, it would be much better to use some kind of a BytesAvailableFcn or DatagramReceivedFcn callback (which allow asynchronous reading without blocking other functions). I am new to socket programming, and unfortunately, this part of Matlab-Java interface is not well documented. I tried (without success so far) to build a callback function by opening a new channel:

```
new_channel =  
    javaMethod('open','java.nio.channels.DatagramChannel');
```

and using a listener function:

```
addlistener(socket,'EventName',@callbackFcn);
```

I would be grateful for any suggestions for a workaround. Because I am new to socket programming, I'll appreciate detailed answers. - Jake.